# Multiplying column values as per their ranges with an another value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with many rows.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Here I want to multiply each column's values as per their ranges with another value.

Like column values between 0 and 10 with 3.2

10-20 with 1.4

20-30 with 5.6

30-40 with 3.2

40-50 with 1.9

50-60 with 3.7

60-70 with 1.1

70-80 with 3.3

80-90 with 1

greater than 90 with 4.

Is there any easy way to do this without indexing for multiple conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use integer division for groups and mapping each column by dictionary with multiple by original column:

```
d = {0:3.2, 1:1.4, 2:5.6, 3:3.2,4:1.9, 5:3.7,6:1.1,7:3.3,8:1,9:4}

out = (df // 10).apply(lambda x: x.map(d)).mul(df)
```

Or use `replace`:

```
out = (df // 10).replace(d).mul(df)
```

Solution for any ranges specified in [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
out = df.apply(lambda x: pd.cut(x, bins=[-1,9,19,29,39,49,59,69,79,89,np.inf],
                                   labels=[3.2, 1.4, 5.6, 3.2, 1.9, 3.7, 1.1, 3.3, 1, 4],
                                   ordered=False)).astype(float).mul(df)
```

Comment: Getting some error while using cut

Comment: @Aristocrat - What is error?

Comment: The error is "cut got an unexpected keyword argument 'ordered'"